# Travelling to Switzerland with covid-19 restrictions

Tags: trains, covid-19, italy, health, switzerland

To travel in Switzerland by train, today it is mandatory to [exhibit a molecular covid-19 test not older than 24h](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/switzerland-lifts-quarantine-obligation-for-all-travellers-imposes-stricter-testing-requirements/). Given that the time I get the test outcome, is usually longer than 24h, how can I get into Switzerland?

Comment: You need to present a PCR test not older than 72 hours.

Comment: See https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/en/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/empfehlungen-fuer-reisende/quarantaene-einreisende.html.

Comment: The page you linked to states "_it has been decided that from now on, **rapid antigen tests will be valid for only 24 hours** and not for 48 hours as they were before. In contrast, **PCR tests continue to be valid for 72 hours**._"

Comment: One obvious answer is to find another way to get a test. I know at least one place where they claim to provide results [from a PCR test within 90 minutes](https://test2fly.amsterdam/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Current restrictions](https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/en/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/empfehlungen-fuer-reisende/quarantaene-einreisende.html) can be found at the official website of the Federal Office of Public Health.

> At various times you will be asked to show a negative test result. These provisions also apply to people who have been vaccinated or recovered from COVID, and regardless of what country they enter from.
>
> On boarding: On boarding, everyone aged 16 and over intending to enter Switzerland by air or bus must be able to show the negative result of a PCR test (**performed no more than 72 hours prior to boarding**). If you cannot show such a test you will not be allowed to board the aircraft or vehicle. Note: For people entering Switzerland from a country with a variant of concern, the test requirement on boarding already applies to those aged 6 and over.
>
> On entry to Switzerland: On entering Switzerland, everyone aged 16 and over intending to enter Switzerland must be able to show the negative result of a PCR test (performed **no more than 72 hours prior to entry**). You must have this test in your country of departure.

Pre-arrival tests must be a PCR test. The post-entry test can be either antigen or PCR test and must be paid by the traveller themselve; cantonal offices are responsible for the enforcement of post-entry tests.

> After entering Switzerland: Once in Switzerland, everyone aged 16 and over must take another PCR test or rapid antigen test between the 4th and 7th day after entry. The test result and the number of the entry form or a copy of the contact card must be notified to the canton. Have you received a negative test result? In this case you must report this to the canton in the form of a COVID test certificate. Have you received a positive test result? In this case, notify the canton of the test result. Contact details for the cantonal authorities are listed further down this page. The costs of the test are borne by the person themselves.

The above conditions apply if you are travelling from a region other than the regions bordering Switzerland. People coming from the following regions are exempt from the testing requirements:

> - Regions in Germany: State of Baden-Württemberg, State of Bavaria
> - Regions in France: Region of Grand-Est, Region of Burgundy / Franche Comté, Region of Auvergne / Rhône-Alpes
> - Regions in Italy: Region of Piedmont, Region of Aosta Valley, Region of Lombardy, Region of Trentino / South Tyrol
> - Regions in Austria: State of Tyrol, State of Vorarlberg
> - Regions in Liechtenstein: Entire Principality

There is currently no clarification on what travelling/entering from a border region means if you enter by trains and private cars. There are usually no systematic controls but random checks could still happen.

Comment: That 'current restrictions' page now shows that since 22nd January 2022, travellers no longer need a test to enter Switzerland if they can show one of the accepted proofs of vaccination.